# Getting the Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.twitter.com api.twitter.com:443 using Node js for twitter posting

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth

```js
const Twitter = require('twitter');

const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: 'XXXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXXX',
  access_token_key: 'XXXX',
  access_token_secret: 'XXXX'
});

client.post('statuses/update', {status: 'Posting via the Node is awesome!'}, function(
  error,
  tweet,
  response
) {
  if (error) throw error;
// console.log(tweet); // Tweet body.
// console.log(response); // Raw response object.
});
```

Please Find Below the error:
if (error) throw error;
^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.twitter.com api.twitter.com:443
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)

Note : I was trying to hit the twitter api using the firewall application proxy. Actually by default api.twitter.com was blocked by firewall but I requested from env team to add the api.twitter.com in  proxy application Link list and they added. Still I am getting the below error  any idea how i can check this what is happening and how to solve this.